# Call a function via crone job laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a `xyz` function in my `ApiController`

```
class Foo
{
    public function xyz()
    {
        // some code to insert data in database
    }
}
```

And I have defined a `route`

```
Route::get('xyz', ['as' => 'xyz', 'uses' => 'ApiController@xyz']);
```

**Now I need to execute the code in `xyz` function in every 10 minutes**

I have successfully set a crone job for one file, in that I am executing a `php` file by simply set command with full path of that file.

I am not getting any clue to execute only one function of a controller via crone job.

Thanks

Comment: take a look on here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling

Comment: I am using `laravel 4.2`

Comment: you can set a url in corn job wget -O /dev/null http://www.test.com/your-url

Comment: what is the meaning of `/dev/null` here

Comment: `wget <output> <input>` this means you don't save the result of the url call.